# Why does Event intent in android not return a result?

Tags: java, android, events, calendar, android-intent

I am creating a event using :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
```

And invoking the intent using

```
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.LINK_CALENDER);
```

There is nothing returned to call in

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

It always returns `data=null` ie., returned `intent result` is always `null`.

I am trying to retrieve the "Done/Revert" state of calender event just created and some identity so that i can open the event again in future from elsewhere in code.

Comment: Hi, Have you found solution? I have the almost the same problem, I want get ID of created event. Details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508511/calendar-event-intent-startactivityforresult

Comment: It's pity, I will have to find different solution

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this activity does return something? Did not find definite proof that it should -or shouldn't- return anything, but that's what I would look up if I where you.

If it doesn't return anything, it's not shocking that you don't get anything as a returnvalue :)

Comment: "It always returns data=null ie., returned intent result is always null." Please see this line again in question :)

Comment: Yes, in your case it does, but _SHOULD_ it return that? Not all intents return something, do they? What I meant was that if an activity does not call the return function, it's not strange you're getting null, right?

Comment: true , agreed, maybe i am expecting more than what the activity can deliver

Comment: Intent.ACTION_EDIT does not return data. Intent.ACTION_INSERT will return the result Intent with Intent.getData() returning the URI of the inserted value. Also CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI can be used for the intent instead. (`intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI`)