# Calendar event intent - startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I want to create an event into the calendar from my app. I can start a new event activity with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT).setData(uri);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ID);
```

Is it possible to **get the ID of the created event**? OnActivityResult resultCode is always 0 - whether I create the event or not. The data is always null. Is there some way to do it?

Comment: Not the ideal solution but good as temporary. I check events count before startActivityForResult and in onActivityReslut. If count is different I know that event was created and I get last inserted event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out the result of my calendar intent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761584/how-can-i-find-out-the-result-of-my-calendar-intent)